# getting image with if condition in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I try to print an image uploaded by user in Laravel 5.4. I use an if condition and if user does not upload any image, then default image is displayed but my source code somehow prints nothing. This the code I use:

```
@if (File::exists($post->image))
    {
        echo "<img src="{{ asset('uploads/' . $post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />";
    } else {
        echo "<img src="{{ asset('images/no-image.png') }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />";
    }
@endif
```

Update:

I try to use this code:

```
@if (File::exists(public_path("asset/uploads/".$post->image)))
    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/' . $post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@else 
    <img src="{{ asset('images/no-image.png') }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@endif
```

And the result now I'm getting:

if i use `asset/uploads` Or `assets/uploads` in `if` all images return to no-image even if they have image.
if I use `uploads` if `if` posts with image shows but other shows no image and the url i'll get for them is `url.dev/uploads` instead of `url.dev/images/no-image.png` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File::exists()` will check the physical location of file in hard disk. So you must use actual path to the file.

```
@if (File::exists(public_path("assets/uploads/".$post->image)))
    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/' . $post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@else 
    <img src="{{ asset('images/no-image.png') }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@endif
```

Cross check the path generated by `public_path' method is correct to your file.

Update: thanks to linktoahref, turns out your blade code is also wrong. Corrected here.

File::exists works same as php's file_exists which will return true even if you search for directory, now what happens here that for some posts image is null which make path a directory.

Use this code instead.

```
@if ($post->image && File::exists(public_path("uploads/".$post->image)))
   <img src="{{ asset('uploads/' . $post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@else 
   <img src="{{ asset('images/no-image.png') }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@endif
```

Comment: My bad! i updated the code with more info please share your idea now.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing raw php and blade templating together, either stick with raw php code or blade templating syntax

So it would be the following in blade

```
@if (File::exists($post->image))
    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/' . $post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@else 
    <img src="{{ asset('images/no-image.png') }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" />
@endif
```

Or use raw php as

```
<?php
 if (File::exists($post->image)) { 
     echo "<img src=". asset('uploads/' . $post->image) . " alt=" . $post->title . " />"; 
 } else { 
     echo "<img src=". asset('images/no-image.png') . " alt=". $post->title ." />"; 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Please check your blade syntax, there is no need of brace

Comment: My bad! i updated the code with more info please share your idea now.